# A Problem occured when deploying gradle project : The project name must not be empty

Tags: java, gradle

Getting the below error when deploying a Gradle project.
The project is not a multi-module Project.

Ideally, it shouldn't have to set root project name when creating a single module project. There is no settings.gradle file.

```
#7 128.0 
#7 128.0 * What went wrong:
#7 128.0 A problem occurred configuring root project ''.
#7 128.0 > The project name must not be empty. Set the 'rootProject.name' or adjust the 'include' statement (see https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String[]) for more details).
```

Comment: Appears to be: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15655